# How to run a timer in initState flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, navigation, screen

I've created an app using flutter and I want to get start a timer when the user navigates to a screen to calculate how long will he stay there.

I want if he has completed three minutes on the screen to print anything.

I don't have any ideas about the timer or how to use it.

please help me regarding achieving that.

thanks all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like that.

```dart
Timer _timer;

@override
void initState() {
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
    // SOMETHING
    });
    super.initState();
}

@override
    void dispose() {
    if (_timer != null) {
        _timer.cancel();
        _timer = null;
    }
    super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: is the nullCheck needed every time or only when the Timer is not started in initState? can it be omitted in this case?

Comment: The timer start again each time I rebuild the page and I have some timers working in parallel. How can I force only one timer?  @ariel

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look of this:

```
    import 'dart:async';
main() {
  const twentyMillis = const Duration(milliseconds:20);
  new Timer(twentyMillis, () => print('hi!'));
}
```

Also look Timer class [link](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Timer-class.html)